# React Router redirect to index

Tags: react-router

i'm using Reactjs, React Router and Relay. The problem is: in my program component, all the link i click redirect to homepage while the url of elements show exactly what i expect. E.g: If i click a link to /community/2/program/3 it redirect me to homepage but when i enter /community/2/program/3 to browser address bar, i can access that page.

My index.js:

```
const rootNode = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(rootNode);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router
    history={browserHistory}
    routes={Route}
    render={applyRouterMiddleware(useRelay)}
    forceFetch
    environment={Relay.Store}
  />,
  rootNode
);
```

My Route:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';

// Queries
import ViewerQuery from './ViewerQuery';
import ProgramQuery from './ProgramQuery';

// Component
import AppContainer from '../components/App/AppContainer';
import FeatureContainer from '../components/Feature/FeatureContainer';

// Container
import ProgramContainer from '../components/Program/ProgramContainer';
import UserContainer from '../components/User/UserContainer';

export default (
  <Route path='/' component={AppContainer} queries={ViewerQuery}>
    <IndexRoute component={FeatureContainer} queries={ViewerQuery} />
    <Route path='/community/:cid' component={ProgramContainer} queries={ProgramQuery} />
    <Route path='/community/:cid/program/:gid' component={UserContainer} queries={ProgramQuery} />
    <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
  </Route>
);
```

Program Component:

```
return (
<ListGroup style = {{paddingLeft: 50, paddingRight: 50, marginBottom:0}}>
                      {this.props.viewer.groups.map((group) => {
                          return (
                                  <Col key={group.groupId} xs={12} md={4} style={{marginTop: 20}}>
                                      <Card shadow={0} style={{width: '100%'}}>
                                          <CardTitle className = {styles.cardTitleBox} style={{color: 'white', height: '176px'}}>
                                              {group.name}
                                          </CardTitle>
                                          <CardText>
                                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                                              Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
                                          </CardText>
                                          <CardActions border>
                                              <Button colored>
                                                  <Link style = {{textDecoration: 'none'}} to= {`${this.props.params.cid}/program/${group.groupId}`}>
                                                      {group.name}
                                                </Link>
                                              </Button>
                                          </CardActions>
                                      </Card>
                                  </Col>

                          );
                      })}
                  </ListGroup>
)
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're just missing a leading slash ?

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation concerning the prop "to" of "Link" component (see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#link) states:

> If it's a string it represents the absolute path to link to, e.g. /users/123 (relative paths are not supported).

So, changing the Link's path to absolute url `/community/${this.props.params.cid}/program/${group.groupId}`
fixes the issue.